# Wrap Scala library in Python

Tags: python, scala, ipc, jpype

There is a Scala library I'd like to use, namely [BIDMach](https://github.com/BIDData/BIDMach), however I need to be able to use it from Python rather than in Scala. I've been trying to think of different ways of possible being able communicate between the library and Python code, such as creating an HTTP server in Scala and calling this from Python, using something like [JPype](http://jpype.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to try and use Scala libraries in Python, and different types of interprocess communication. However, none of them seem to work very well, and would seem to require a large amount of reimplementation of what is already in the library. Does anyone know of a good way of going about this?

edit: In terms of exactly what I think I'd like to do, ideally I'd be able to get close to almost all of the libraries functionality usable in Python, however that probably isn't realistic. It would be nice if some of the Scala classes were easily usable in Python, without too much repeated implementation effort. The reason I don't think what I've looked into so far will work well is because it requires a fair bit of reimplementation of what is already in the library  (i.e. representing something like a matrix in JSON, as a way of transporting data to/from Python/Scala)

Comment: Is using [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) an option? A JVM-hosted Python will make interop with Scala dramatically simpler.

Comment: More information would be good.  In my experience, Python's various subprocess functions (things like subprocess.call or subrocess.Popen) can work very well for accessing functionality written in other languages and wrapped to be usable via pipes/files/commandline arguments.  So what exactly do you mean by "none of them seem to work very well"?

Comment: I'll look into Jython. If it plays well with Scala, it's definitely an option. I've updated the post with more information.

Comment: Am working on the same project, can you send me a message ?
https://github.com/arita291
Thanks